# How can I clear my Gallery view before leaving an activity?

Tags: android, view, android-activity, gallery

I have two Activities in my App, one is a `ListView` which displays a list of items.  When a user clicks one of these items, it opens up a new Activity which then downloads a bunch of thumbnails from a website and displays them in a `Gallery`.  Currently, when I click the back button from the 2nd view and then select a new item from the `ListView`, when the 2nd `Activity` is displayed again the gallery still shows the old images until the new images are downloaded.  How can I clear out the gallery before it is displayed after the 2nd ListView item click?

Comment: Do you finishing Gallery Activity before return to List Activity ?

Comment: set galleryAdapter.setListAdapter(null) when you leaving from 2nd activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever list or array of items is backing your Gallery's adapter, just clear it and then call adapter.[notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29). You can do this in the onPause() callback of your 2nd Activity.

Comment: Thanks.  I was trying this before, but I wasn't saving an instance of the adapter and list in my class, so I was calling findViewByID in OnPause to get the Gallery, and then I would get the adapter from that but it would give me a nullpointer exception.